# How can I determine what is taking up so much space?

Tags: centos, bash, disk-space-utilization

I was using df -h to print out human readable disk usage. I would like to figure out what is taking up so much space. For instance, is there a way to pipe this command so that it prints out files that are larger than 1GB in size? Other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I use WinDirStat on windows, really interested if there is a CLI equivalent for *NIX

Comment: `filelight` is a nice GUI app for Linux

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I use this one a lot.

```
du -kscx *
```

It can take a while to run, but it'll tell you where the disk space is being used.

Comment: I use a variant on this, I use the h flag instead of k, which will give you a similarly "human readable" format as df will.

Comment: The advantage is that with the `-k` switch 20MB in kilobytes is a much smaller number than 2GB in kilobytes... easier to `| sort -n`

Answer (score 42):

You may want to try the `ncdu` utility found at: http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu

It will quicky sum the contents of a filesystem or directory tree and print the results, sorted by size. It's a really nice way to drill-down interactively and see what's consuming drive space.

Additionally, it can be faster than some `du` combinations.

The typical output looks like:

```
ncdu 1.7 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help                                                         
--- /data ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  163.3GiB [##########] /docimages                                                                                  
   84.4GiB [#####     ] /data
   82.0GiB [#####     ] /sldata
   56.2GiB [###       ] /prt
   40.1GiB [##        ] /slisam
   30.8GiB [#         ] /isam
   18.3GiB [#         ] /mail
   10.2GiB [          ] /export
    3.9GiB [          ] /edi   
    1.7GiB [          ] /io     
    1.2GiB [          ] /dmt
  896.7MiB [          ] /src
  821.5MiB [          ] /upload
  691.1MiB [          ] /client
  686.8MiB [          ] /cocoon
  542.5MiB [          ] /hist
  358.1MiB [          ] /savsrc
  228.9MiB [          ] /help
  108.1MiB [          ] /savbin
  101.2MiB [          ] /dm
   40.7MiB [          ] /download
```

Comment: +1 - I've been meaning to figure this out myself for a while.  BTW, `ncdu` is also available via yum (CentOS, RHEL, Fedora) using the epel repo: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL.  `sudo ncdu -q /` works nicely over ssh.  I really like the way I can drill down into folders using the arrow keys.

Comment: +1 this tool is just the best !

Comment: Oh ncdu where have you been all my life.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the find command.  Example:

```
find /home/ -size +1073700000c -print
```

Comment: Newer versions of GNU find also support M (Megabytes) as a modifier. ie `find /path -size +1024M`

Answer (score 7):

I myself use

```
du -c --max-depth=4 /dir | sort -n
```

this returns amount of space used by a directory and its subdirectories up to 4 deep, `sort -n` will put the largest last.

New versions of `sort` can handle "human-readable" sizes, so one can use much more readable

```
du -hc --max-depth=4 /dir | sort -h
```

Answer (score 2):

With human readable sizes:

```
du -hscx *
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Recursively search for big files in one directory

As I haved to *determine what is taking up so much space?* a lot of time, I wrote this little script in order to search for big occupation on a specific device (without argument, this will browse current directory, searching for **>256Mb** directory entries):

```
#!/bin/bash

humansize() {
    local _c=$1 _i=0 _a=(b K M G T P)
    while [ ${#_c} -gt 3 ] ;do
    ((_i++))
    _c=$((_c>>10))
    done
    _c=$(( ( $1*1000 ) >> ( 10*_i ) ))
    printf ${2+-v} $2 "%.2f%s" ${_c:0:${#_c}-3}.${_c:${#_c}-3} ${_a[_i]}
}

export device=$(stat -c %d "${1:-.}")
export minsize=${2:-$((256*1024**2))}

rdu() {
    local _dir="$1" _spc="$2" _crt _siz _str
    while read _crt;do
    if [ $(stat -c %d "$_crt") -eq $device ];then
            _siz=($(du -xbs "$_crt"))
            if [ $_siz -gt $minsize ];then
        humansize $_siz _str
        printf "%s%12s%14s_%s\n" "$_spc" "$_str" \\ "${_crt##*/}"
        [ $d "$_crt" ] && rdu "$_crt" "  $_spc"
        fi
    fi
    done < <(
    find "$_dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print
    )
}

rdu "${1:-.}"
```

Sample of use:

```
./rdu.sh /usr 100000000
       1.53G             \_lib
       143.52M             \_i386-linux-gnu
       348.16M             \_x86_64-linux-gnu
       107.80M             \_jvm
         100.20M             \_java-6-openjdk-amd64
           100.17M             \_jre
              99.65M             \_lib
       306.63M             \_libreoffice
         271.75M             \_program
       107.98M             \_chromium
      99.57M             \_lib32
     452.47M             \_bin
       2.50G             \_share
       139.63M             \_texlive
         129.74M             \_texmf-dist
       478.36M             \_locale
       124.49M             \_icons
       878.09M             \_doc
         364.02M             \_texlive-latex-extra-doc
           359.36M             \_latex
```

Little check:

```
du -bs /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist
136045774   /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist
echo 136045774/1024^2 | bc -l
129.74336051940917968750
```

Nota: using `-b` instead of `-k` tell `du` to sumarize only used bytes, but not effective reserved space (by block of 512 bytes). For working about blocs size, you have to change line `du -xbs ...` by `du -xks`, suppress `b` in `_a=(K M G T P)` and divide argument size by 1024.

... There is a modified version (I will keep for myself) using *blocks* sizes by default, but accepting `-b` as first argument for bytes calculation:

#### Edit: New version

After some work about, there is a newer version a lot **quicker** and with output sorted in descending size order:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "-b" ] ;then
    shift
    export units=(b K M G T P)
    export duargs="-xbs"
    export minsize=${2:-$((256*1024**2))}
else
    export units=(K M G T P)
    export duargs="-xks"
    export minsize=${2:-$((256*1024))}
fi

humansize() {
    local _c=$1 _i=0
    while [ ${#_c} -gt 3 ] ;do
    ((_i++))
    _c=$((_c>>10))
    done
    _c=$(( ( $1*1000 ) >> ( 10*_i ) ))
    printf ${2+-v} $2 "%.2f%s" ${_c:0:${#_c}-3}.${_c:${#_c}-3} ${units[_i]}
}

export device=$(stat -c %d "${1:-.}")

rdu() {
    local _dir="$1" _spc="$2" _crt _siz _str
    while read _siz _crt;do
        if [ $_siz -gt $minsize ];then
        humansize $_siz _str
        printf "%s%12s%14s_%s\n" "$_spc" "$_str" \\ "${_crt##*/}"
        [ -d "$_crt" ] &&
        [ $(stat -c %d "$_crt") -eq $device ] &&
            rdu "$_crt" "  $_spc"
    fi
    done < <(
    find "$_dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -xdev \
        \( -type f -o -type d \) -printf "%D;%p\n" |
        sed -ne "s/^${device};//p" |
        tr \\n \\0 |
        xargs -0 du $duargs |
        sort -nr
    )
}

rdu "${1:-.}"
```

Answer (score 1):

To display the biggest top-20 directories in the current folder, use the following one-liner:

```
du -ah . | sort -rh | head -20
```

or:

```
du -a . | sort -rn | head -20
```

For the top-20 biggest files in the current directory (recursively):

```
ls -1Rs | sed -e "s/^ *//" | grep "^[0-9]" | sort -nr | head -n20
```

or with human readable sizes:

```
ls -1Rhs | sed -e "s/^ *//" | grep "^[0-9]" | sort -hr | head -n20
```

> The second command to work on OSX/BSD properly (as `sort` doesn't have `-h`), you need to install `sort` from `coreutils`. Then add the bin folder to your `PATH`.

So these aliases are useful to have in your *rc* files (every time when you need it):

```
alias big='du -ah . | sort -rh | head -20'
alias big-files='ls -1Rhs | sed -e "s/^ *//" | grep "^[0-9]" | sort -hr | head -n20'
```