# Find files/folders that are filling up disk space

Tags: linux, bash, files, maintenance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I determine what is taking up so much space?](https://serverfault.com/questions/301423/how-can-i-determine-what-is-taking-up-so-much-space)

I just had an old server go belly up because it ran out of drive space. I am logged in to the shell, and I'm trying to find more unused files to remove.

Is there shell a command, script, or app that will display the largest files/folders?

Answer (score 8):

This command will help you find big directories 5 levels deep. It also orders the directories by the size.

I had a similar problem long time ago where apache sessions where filling my disk and slowing down my web server.

```
du --max-depth=5 /* | sort -rn
```

Comment: my busybox did not have --max-depth so I had to use `du -d 5`

Answer (score 4):

The largest top 10 files and directories with size in a human-readable format:

```
du -shx /* | sort -rh | head
```

Comment: Perfect. And then you can drill down into subdirectories by modifying the command, ie, `du -shx /var/* | sort -rh | head`  where "var" is the subdirectory you want to investigate. I used this a few levels deep until I found the individual file that was causing issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
du -h --max-depth=1 /
```

and then work your way down the filesystem till you find it.

If it's a long running system, the chances are high that it's a log file that has filled the disk. If that's the case then make sure you shutdown the process that's writing to it before archiving/deleting it as just deleting often doesn't recover the disk space.

Answer (score 2):

The `du` command will get you this information. For example:

```
cd /
du -sm *
9   bin
18  boot
1   dev
6   etc
685 export
1   home
...
```