# Web-based disk space visualizer

Tags: linux, hard-drive, disk-space-utilization, headless, visualization

I have a number of Linux webservers for which I'd like to track where disk space is going and keep disk space to a minimum.

Typically I login on SSH and use `du` to find out where disk space is wasted but this is cumbersome and slow. A visualisation tool like KDirStat would be ideal, but it requires installing an X server at the very least, which kind of defeats the purpose.

Is there any web-based disk space visualizer? I'm open to alternative solutions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine what is taking up so much space?](http://serverfault.com/questions/301423/how-can-i-determine-what-is-taking-up-so-much-space)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use `ncdu` - http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu, which has been covered here often. I also recommend a monitoring suite ([Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/), Nagios, etc.) that can alert on a preset filesystem utilization percentage... Then use a tool like [ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) to understand what comprises the nearly-full filesystem.

But there's also [Philesight](http://zevv.nl/play/code/philesight/), which is a web-based CGI script: http://zevv.nl/play/code/philesight/

*Philesight is designed to run on a remote server without graphical user interface.*

It presents a pie chart.

[image]

Comment: To anything coming here in 2019+ check out Duc https://duc.zevv.nl/ it replaced Philesight.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to install [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) on one of your servers.You can monitor disk usage ,cpu usage , memory usage etc.

Cacti is a complete frontend to RRDTool, it stores all of the necessary information to create graphs and populate them with data in a MySQL database. 
The frontend is completely PHP driven. And you can add all other servers to it.So you will have everything on one place.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

[phpsysinfo](http://phpsysinfo.sourceforge.net/) - but you'll have to have php on servers (which you most likely have, since your servers are webservers)