# list of size of directories of /dev/sda mounted as / without other partition or mounter

Tags: linux, unix

as you can see here:

```
Filesystem                                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                            13G  332K   13G   1% /run
/dev/sda1                                        20G   19G  747M  97% /
tmpfs                                           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                            26G   13M   26G   1% /run/shm
/dev/mapper/pve-data                            533G  380G  127G  75% /var/lib/vz
```

my main partition /dev/sda1 is completly full, 747M free only.
But I'm not able to determine where are those few gigas a I had free a few month ago.

my log directory is not the problem, less than 2 gigas. I tried to make du folder by folder in the / without the /var/lib/vz, but still, I can't see what's taking so much size.

Is there a anyway to make something like this du /dev/sda1/* -hs ?
obsiously it didn't work for me, but that what I would like to know.

I did also that

```
du -csh / --exclude=/var/lib/vz --exclude=/mnt
```

and the results is

```
2.5G    /
2.5G    total
```

Best regards and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the `ncdu` command to determine your filesystem utilization.

Also see: [How can I determine what is taking up so much space?](https://serverfault.com/questions/301423/how-can-i-determine-what-is-taking-up-so-much-space/301434#301434)

Answer (score 0):

You can investigate where your disk is used by using the `tree` command.

`tree --du -h /`

will print the directory tree with file and directory sizes. Take a look at the man-page for `tree` for further parameters. For example you might want to limit the depth by using the `-L` option.