# zsh: locking failed for /home/centos/.zsh_history: no space left on device: reading anyway

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos7, disk-space-utilization, xfs

I am using CentOS image from AWS EC2, I have root volume attached which is 150 GB and I see below error message after I login

```
zsh: locking failed for /home/centos/.zsh_history: no space left on device: reading anyway
```

[image: disk space full]

In, AWS EC2 I can increase the size of the root volume and run below commands into the server to increase the disk space

> lsblk 
>   sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1 
>   sudo xfs_growfs -d /

My question is will the error message get removed if I increase the disk space as I want to be sure?

Please help

Comment: If / is the only file system (and /home(/centos) is not on its own filesystem) then yes you can increase the diskspace (and root file system) to get rid of it. - Typically you would first check WHY you run out of disk space, if it is because of actual data you want to keep, or bad house keeping.  If it is the latter potentially you can free a lot of space by cleaning up old data, excessive log files etc. ...

Comment: @HBruijn: yes, I think that too, Do you know any command where I can list all files which is consuming the server space?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/301423/37681

Comment: @HBruijn: Thanks. Just one thing / is the only filesystem I have. Also I am not able to know where the disk space is been utilized. Server is 150 GB and I'm sure that application is using 50GB only and 100 GB should be free but dont know how to find it Any Idea?